# Matplotlib - transform bbox

Tags: matplotlib

I printed some text into a plot. Now I want to make a copy of this text and move it to different coordinates. I guess I'll have to do this with tranform, but did not find a solution yet.

here is the code:

```
props = dict( facecolor='#DDDDDD', alpha=1,edgecolor='#FFFFFF',boxstyle="Square,pad=0.5")
text2=plt.text(4, 4, "text",va='top', ha='left',bbox=props)
plt.draw()
bb2=text2.get_bbox_patch().get_window_extent().transformed(ax.transData.inverted()).get_points()
```

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what do you mean. It's better to provide a picture and well-organized codes.

Answer (score 1):

To move the text to different coordinates you only need:

```
text2.set_position((new_x,new_y))
```

you could also use:

```
text2.set_x(new_x)
text2.set_y(new_y)
```